# adding extra column to the admin user table magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database, admin, admin-user

I am tring to add new column to the magento admin user by scripting and manually also both are not working, when i try to add manually it is giving the error "Invalid default value for created" [image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi it  will not add any column ,till you  either delete the column `created` or edit the column and  change its default value .

ps  : after doing this there could be other column for  which this error will be thrown edit them too and change the default value . you  would be able to add extra columns

The same happened to me when i used a table  from my m1 website  and  moved it to to m2 version of the same website ..